# Can sleep() in c++ in unix environment be used as the same as delay() in Turbo C++ for windows?

Tags: delayed-execution

In Turbo C++:

```
while(i<10)
{delay(100);
cout<<"*";
i++;}
```

will print "*" after a regular intervals of 100 milliseconds. If I try to do the same in C++ in UNIX like:

```
while(i<10)
{
sleep(1);
cout<<"*";
i++;}
```

it prints "*" 10 times after a single interval of 10 seconds at once.

Please, can someone explain why is it not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `cout` is often buffered by default. If you want it printed immediately, flush it:

```
std::cout << "*" << std::flush;
```